# Extract embedding of a certain token from a 3D tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Each training example contains a sentence (a list of tokens), a start token index and an end token index. The start and end index highlight some words in the sentence. The label is either True or False, which indicates the highlighted word is "interesting" or not.
For example, "news" is the highlighted word in this example.

```
tokens=["This", "news", "is", "sad"], start=1, end=2, label=1
```

Here is my model setup.
The sentences are feeded to the pre-trainied bert layer, which returns a 3D tensor which contain s the embedding of each tokens in every sentences.

I'd like to extract the embedding of the highligted words of each exampel from the 3D tensor and get the mean of them, so that I can feed it to a dense layer, how should I do that? Assuming I already have the 3D tensor.

I am using keras API proivded by tensorflow 2.0.
I am new to tensorflow, so a concrete example would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add what you got so far in terms of the code?

Comment: Updated the question a bit. Please assume me I already have the 3D tesnor (in eager execution mode)

Comment: Also can you update what `tokens`,  `start`, `end`, `label` look like for a batch of data.

Comment: is there some sort of a guarantee that you'll have a fixed number of start end pairs per example or could that vary between examples?

Comment: it varies between example.